# IS there some how to specify dinamically the Hub Name of Azure SignalR at the negotiate of Azure Serverless Solution?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, signalr, azure-signalr

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService;

namespace TheNameSpace
{
    public static class Function
    {
        [FunctionName("Negotiate")]
        public static SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, Route = "v1/Negotiate")] HttpRequest req,
            [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "serverless")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
        {
            return connectionInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function to negotiate - You will find this sample in many others portals or sources. Yes, it works good! But I'd like to specify dynamically the HubName.

On the example above, it's hardcoded and I think it's not possible to be dynamic. I'd like something like HubName = Req.Query("HubName")

How to archive it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```cs
[SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "{query.HubName}")]
```

Comment: Can you expand on this?  Is HubName a query parameter?  so should it be passed as ?HubName=MyHubName

Comment: Yes, the HubName is an *url query parameter* of the http request. In the case of using the request header, it will be *{headers.HubName}*, also we can use a route value.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this capability existed for Azure functions.  Can you dir3ect me to where this is documented?  How would it be configured for route value?  I assume the route needs to be configured as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "{query.HubName}")]
```

for passing the hub name from the request query

or

```
[SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "{headers.HubName}")]
```

for passing the hub name from the request header

You can find more info regarding input binding here:    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-input?tabs=isolated-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp